# uiwebview is not loading index.html the second time

Tags: uiwebview

I have an app that I load in a uiwebview, it first load a splashscreen 
and then the index.html file(the menu), fine, just as it should!

But if I navigate to a different page eg page2.html and then close the 
app, and then start it again, then it is not loading the splashscreen 
and it does not load the index.html file, instead it loads the page it 
was on when the app was closed, the page2.html.

Has anybody the same problem? And a solution to it? 
Thanks, Claes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using iOS4? If so, it's highly likely the application was still running in background after you pressed the Home button.

The video [here](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-close-out-applications-completely-new-iphone-ios-4-377560/) shows you how to close the applications running in background.

Comment: Hi, yes it is 4.
I load all the file from the within the app, so the index.html is not on the server. 

Another app that I made with 3.1 is working just fine, showing the splashscreen and loads the index file everytime. And it is the same code that I use to load the splash and index file.
So why is it working with the old one and not since I upgraded to 4?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I looked at the video, that explanes everything!
Do you know if it is possible to to close it completly, when you close the app so it is not running in the background?